# From Exchange To Wallet

Tags: wallet

I have some crypto on 2 exchanges and I cant work out if it will cost me any type of fee to transfer into a wallet. Specifically Coinbase to Coinbase Wallet and Binance to Trust Wallet.

Regards,

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Withdrawals fees are individual per specific exchange and in many cases they don't relate to the current bitcoin feerate.

So you'd have to check your Coinbase and Binance exchange account, in the withdrawal section to see how much fees are they taking for withdrawal.